# Touchscreen doest work with Debian 9.13 and HX controller

Tags: linux, debian, usb, touchscreen

Sharp Monitor with Touchscreen Frame connected by USB and HDMI to a PC.
Debian 9.13 (4.9.0-16-amd64)

When SO boot, touchscreen doesnt works when I press on it, but it works if I unplug and plug the USB.

This is my config:

Added to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/53-touchscreen.conf for catch all events and ignore HX Touch Device Pen

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "HX Touch catchall"
    MatchProduct "HX Touch Device"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "HX Touch Pen deactive"
    MatchProduct "HX Touch Device Pen"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchVendor "HX"
    Driver "void"
    Option "Ignore"
EndSection
```

### Info on boot

xinput

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HX Touch Device                           id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput --list-props 9

```
Device 'HX Touch Device':
        Device Enabled (133):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix (272):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix Default (273):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (255):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (256):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (257):        0, 0
        Device Node (258):      "/dev/input/event4"
        Device Product ID (259):        1245, 40593
```

dmesg

```
[    1.873563] usb 1-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[    1.874157] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04dd, idProduct=9e91
[    1.874160] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.874162] usb 1-2: Product: Touch Device
[    1.874164] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HX
[    2.643435] input: HX Touch Device Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0002/input/input3
[    2.644115] input: HX Touch Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0002/input/input4
[    2.649479] hid-multitouch 0003:04DD:9E91.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v2.00 Mouse [HX Touch Device] on usb-0000:00:15.0-2/input0
```

udevadm info --query=all --attribute-walk /dev/input/event4

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0002/input/input4/event4':
    KERNEL=="event4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0002/input/input4':
    KERNELS=="input4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="HX Touch Device"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:15.0-2/input0"
    ATTRS{properties}=="2"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0002':
    KERNELS=="0003:04DD:9E91.0002"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-multitouch"
    ATTRS{country}=="00"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="4112"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="Touch Device"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2':
    KERNELS=="1-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="5001"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9e91"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="HX"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="Touch Device"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="17"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0409"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.9.0-16-amd64 xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="8"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:15.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="44"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:15.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x5aa8"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="365"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x7270"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

### Info after reattach usb cable and touchscreen starts to work

dmesg

```
[  619.750184] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  630.026900] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  630.167200] usb 1-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[  630.167827] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04dd, idProduct=9e91
[  630.167830] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  630.167833] usb 1-2: Product: Touch Device
[  630.167845] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HX
[  630.185722] input: HX Touch Device Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0003/input/input11
[  630.186097] input: HX Touch Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0003/input/input12
[  630.186467] hid-multitouch 0003:04DD:9E91.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v2.00 Mouse [HX Touch Device] on usb-0000:00:15.0-2/input0
```

xinput --list-props 9

```
Device 'HX Touch Device':
        Device Enabled (133):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix (272):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix Default (273):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (255):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (256):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (257):        0, 0
        Device Node (258):      "/dev/input/event4"
        Device Product ID (259):        1245, 40593
```

udevadm info --query=all --attribute-walk /dev/input/event4

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0003/input/input12/event4':
    KERNEL=="event4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0003/input/input12':
    KERNELS=="input12"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="HX Touch Device"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:15.0-2/input0"
    ATTRS{properties}=="2"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:04DD:9E91.0003':
    KERNELS=="0003:04DD:9E91.0003"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-multitouch"
    ATTRS{country}=="00"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="4112"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="Touch Device"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2':
    KERNELS=="1-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="5001"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9e91"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="HX"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="Touch Device"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1621"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0409"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.9.0-16-amd64 xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="8"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:15.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="66"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:15.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x5aa8"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="366"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x7270"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

I dont know why is not working on boot, but yes when I uplug and plug the Usb cable.

Comment: is it possible to modify KERNELS value?

Comment: I have tried to reset the usb from the console and it has not worked either. Neither does updating the kernel from backport work

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 didnt work

Comment: same on fedora 34 `5.15.12-100.fc34`
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684954/touchscreen-device-doesnt-work-after-boot-but-does-on-replug

Answer (score 0):

First, i didnt found a solution for the Problem yet.
But i have a workaround which could be helpful for you.

You can unload the `hid_multitouch` with `modprobe -r hid_multitouch`and it will start working.

**BUT:** since we unloaded the `hid_multitouch` module the touch will be recognized as a mouse-pointer-device. You can check `xinput --list` output for more information.

So all events you do are normal mouse events.
This will bring up other problems (no pinch-zoom as example).

Reloading the `hid_multitouch` with `modprobe hid_multitouch` doesnt work, or in other words doesnt turn on the touch functions as expected. it will not do anything ...

you can find my observations on
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684954/touchscreen-device-doesnt-work-after-boot-but-does-on-replug